# Ubuntu 18.04 wired connection unreachable when not logged in

Tags: networking, network-manager, remote-desktop

I set up Ubuntu 18.04 to be able to use RDP from a Windows machine to Ubuntu. In order to get a Windows machine to RDP to Ubuntu 18.04 user has to be logged off the Ubuntu machine.

When I log off Ubuntu with wifi turned off and try to ping the wired network connection ping says the host is unreachable. When I log into Ubuntu then the wired connection is reachable. Ping gives me a 1ms  reply time.

With Wifi I can RDP into the Ubuntu machine when I am logged off.

Why is the wired connection unreachable when I am not logged on?

Comment: really unclear. Try to be precise: there is no way to understand where is the rdp server, what wifi and wired network stands out and so and so...

Comment: Everything is on a local network(192.168.1.x/24  Windows 10 is the RDP Client. Ubuntu 18.04 is the RDP Server.  For Ubuntu to work as an RDP server no on can be logged into the Ubuntu machine. Ubuntu machine has both a wireless card and a wired NIC. The wireless card on the Ubuntu machine provides a connection with both the Ubuntu User logged on and logged off. The wired NIC card provides a "Host Unreachable" message when pinged with the Win10 client and another Linux computer when there is NO User logged into the Ubuntu 18 RDP Server.  When a user is logged into Ubuntu, ping gives ms reading.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings/Wired Network and check "Make available to other users". This will allow log on of wired network before a user is logged on.